# Any idea why I can't disable backups?

Tags: backend, magento2.3.3, backup

Any idea why I can't disable backups in Magento 2.3.3?

I've tried through the admin panel and when I change the enabled setting from "yes" to "no" and save the page, it still shows "yes" when the page refreshes. I tried disabling the automatic backups first and then disabling backups entirely, but when I save the settings and the page refreshes, both still show "yes".

[image]

I tried through the command line using:

`bin/magento config:set system/backup/functionality_enabled 0`

and get: `value saved` in response, but when I go back to the control panel in Magento and check, it shows that backups are still enabled.

I tried clearing the caches, then tried blowing away the caches. I also tried a complete reindexing and there was no difference.

As far as I can tell any/all other settings in the Magento panel are behaving as expected, so it seems that the problem is isolated to backup settings...

Anyone seen this before, or have an idea what to look at to get these backup jobs shut off?

Comment: check the cache, that maybe your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the backups via the Magento back-end are actually disabled. Here's what we see when checking the database:

+-----------+---------+----------+------------------------------------+----------+
| config_id | scope   | scope_id | path                               | value    |
+-----------+---------+----------+------------------------------------+----------+
|        99 | default |        0 | system/backup/functionality_enabled| 0        |
|       100 | default |        0 | system/backup/enabled              | 0        |

so this must be an admin. interface problem of some kind.

Blowing away the caches and reindexing **several times** eventually caught things up with the database.